# Pythonanywhere returning BadStatusLine when I am trying to get request of Airbnb through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere

This is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
import io
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


neighbours = []

with io.open('cntr_london.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for q in f:
            neighbours.append(q.replace('neighborhoods%5B%5D=', '').replace('\n',''))

#url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/paris/homes?room_types%5B%5D=Entire%20home%2Fapt&room_types%5B%5D=Private%20room&price_max=' +str(price_max)+ '&price_min=' + str(price_min)

def scroll_through_bottom():
        s = 0
        while s <= 4000:
            s = s+200
            browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, '+ str(s) +');')


def get_links():
    link_data = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_1szwzht')
    for link in link_data:
        link_tag = link.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for l in link_tag:
            link_list.append(l.get_attribute("href"))

    length = len(link_list)
    print length 


with Display():

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    try:
        browser.get('http://airbnb.com')
    finally:
        browser.quit()
```

Every url is working. But when I am trying to get Airbnb, it is giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "airbnb_new.py", line 43, in <module>
    browser.get('http://airbnb.com')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 234, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 433, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1089, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 408, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

On the other hand, when I am trying to run my code in Python3, it is giving me `no module named pyvirtualdisplay` even though I installed it with pip.

Can someone please help me with this problem? I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: why don't you try to catch the exception and take a look at what the airbnb response is etc?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Airbnb has identified your **scraper** and as a preventive measure they are rejecting requests from your spider. So you can not do anything may be you can change IP and system info and check if it works or you can wait for couple of hour and check if airbnb system has released lock and accepting requests from your system too.

Comment: Can I change system info in `Pythonanywhere`? Or is it happening because of older version of firefox?

Comment: Is it possible for you to change system and IP ?

Comment: In firefox, I can change proxies. Do I need to change user-agent also?

Comment: @MaheshKaria Can you help me to understand how you concluded `Airbnb has identified your scrapper`?

Comment: Airbnb has not identified my scraper. I am getting responds in facebook, google and any other websites but it is not working with Airbnb. After researching, I got that, firefox driver version maybe the cause. It too old and version is 17. On the other hand there is no way to upgrade firefox. So what should I do now!